# Merging Communities and finding a community by its member

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, merge, set

**Problem Statement**

People connect with each other in a social network. A connection between Person I and Person J is represented as M I J. When two persons belonging to different communities connect, the net effect is the merger of both communities which I and J belongs to.

At the beginning, there are N people representing N communities. Suppose person 1 and 2 connected and later 2 and 3 connected, then 1,2, and 3 will belong to the same community.

There are two type of queries:

M I J => communities containing person I and J merged (if they belong to different communities).

Q I => print the size of the community to which person I belongs.

**My approach:**

I created an empty set of sets. When two people merged, I am checking all the inner sets, if found any of them, I am adding them to that set and breaking out.
If not I am creating a new inner set with those persons.
Now in this parent set, I need to compare all inner sets with each other, if an intersection is found, I should combine both of the inner sets, which I am not able to do.

Is my approach correct? But this is very iterative process, is there a better way to solve it?

**My code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nPeople = sc.nextInt();
        int queries = sc.nextInt();
        Set<Set<Integer>> community = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<queries ; i++){
           char query = sc.next().charAt(0);
           if(query == 'Q'){
                int p = sc.nextInt();
                Set<Integer> tmpset = new HashSet<Integer>();

                for( Set<Integer> innerSet : community){
                   for(Integer person : innerSet) {
                       if( person == p ){
                           for(Integer each : innerSet){
                               tmpset.add(each);
                           }
                       }
                   }
                }

                if(tmpset.size()!= 0) {
                    System.out.println(tmpset.size());
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("1");
                }
            }
            else if(query=='M'){
                int person1 = sc.nextInt();
                int person2 = sc.nextInt();

                int c = 0;

                loop:
                for( Set<Integer> innerSet : community){
                   for(Integer person : innerSet) {
                       if( person == person1 || person == person2){
                           innerSet.add(person1);
                           innerSet.add(person2);
                           c++;
                           break loop;

                       }
                   }
                }

                if(c==0){
                     Set<Integer> tmpset = new HashSet<Integer>();
                     tmpset.add(person1);
                     tmpset.add(person2);
                     community.add(tmpset);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

My code ouput: Set containing sets.

[image]

Problem link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merging-communities

Solved it with the help of @Adamski ,using disjoint sets data structure, but still not so efficient solution.

**Code:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nPeople = sc.nextInt();
        DisJoint comm = new DisJoint(nPeople);
        int queries = sc.nextInt();
        for(int k = 0 ; k<queries ; k++){
            char query = sc.next().charAt(0);
            if(query == 'Q'){
               int person = sc.nextInt(); 
               int personParent = comm.Find(person);
               int community = 0;
               for(int j =1 ; j<nPeople+1 ; j++){
                   int tmpParent = comm.Find(j);
                   if(personParent == tmpParent){
                       community++;
                   }
               }
               System.out.println(community);
            }
            if(query == 'M'){
                int person1 = sc.nextInt();
                int person2 = sc.nextInt();
                comm.Union(person1,person2);
            }
        }

    }
}

 class DisJoint{
    public int Count;
    public int[] Parent;
    public int[] Rank;
    public DisJoint(int count){
        this.Count = count;
        this.Parent = new int[this.Count+1];
        this.Rank = new int[this.Count+1];
        for (int i = 1; i < this.Count+1; i++) {
            this.Parent[i] = i;
            this.Rank[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    public int Find(int i){
        if(i == Parent[i]){
            return Parent[i];
        }
        else{
           int result = Find(Parent[i]);
           Parent[i] = result;
           return result;
        }
    }

    public void  Union(int a, int b){
        if(a>b){
            int tmp = a;
            a = b;
            b = tmp;
        }
        int aroot = this.Find(a);
        int broot = this.Find(b);
        int arank = Rank[aroot];
        int brank = Rank[broot];

        if (aroot == broot){
           return;
        }
        if (arank < brank) {
           this.Parent[aroot] = broot;
         } 
        else if (arank > brank) {
          this.Parent[broot] = aroot;
         }
        else{
          this.Parent[aroot] = broot;
          Rank[broot]++;
        }
    }

}
```

Please test the code in the mentioned link.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a data structure to represent disjoint sets?  For example here: http://www.mathblog.dk/disjoint-set-data-structure/

The basic premise is that you define a class (e.g. `Person`) and represent your set of communities as a single array.  Each `Person` contains an index back into the array, either pointing to itself or to another `Person`:

```
| Adam | Dave | Fred | Tom | James |
| 0    | 0    | 1    | 3   | 3     |
```

In the above example, to test whether Fred and Dave are in the same community you start at each Person and follow the graph to the root person; i.e. the person whose index references itself:

```
Fred -> Dave -> Adam
Dave -> Adam
```

(Clearly there's an optimisation here in that during the first traversal you actually encounter Dave before reaching the root.)

In contrast, testing whether James and Fred in the same community:

```
James -> Tom
Fred -> Dave -> Adam
```

The people have different roots and hence belong to different communities.

Merging communities is then a case of repointing one community's root person to another community's root.

Deducing the size of the community is more complex; I'll leave this as an exercise for you to figure out!

Comment: FWIW, with path compression and union-by-rank, this approach is O(α(n)) per operation, where α is the inverse Ackermann function. So it is extremely efficient

Comment: @Adamski for deducing the size of the community, I am checking the parent of queryPerson and then checking parent of every element of the set with a counter and returning the value of the counter as community size. Please check in the question section, I have added this code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, regarding your code. it is poor OO design:

1. everything is in one method (did you consider making separate methods for 'Q' and 'M'?)
2. all the variables are local to that method

Now, regarding the solution, I took another approach:

1. a person always belongs to only one community.  so I have a "world" data strucutre that is able to directly tell me the community of any specified person. it can be a Map where key is person and community is value. I chose a List where the index is person and value is community.
2. once you have that, it is easy to find the community of any specified person (I have a specific method that does just that)
3. once you have this ability to find a community, Q' operaion becomes a given (size of list, duh) and together with "world" 'M' operation is also easy (guess what, I have a specific method that does just that...)

So I have created the following code (tested and working)
Note: since in the problem, indexes start from 1, I defined "world" with size == nPeople and its 0 index is not used.

```
public class Solution
{
    // data structure: index is person and value is community
    static List<Integer> world;

    // input 
    static int nPeople, queries;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        System.out.println("people operations:");
        init();

        for (int i = 0; i < queries; i++) {
            System.out.println("next operation:");
            char operation = sc.next().charAt(0);
            switch (operation) {
            case 'Q':
                System.out.println(query(sc.nextInt()));
                break;
            case 'M':
                merge(sc.nextInt(), sc.nextInt());
                System.out.println("done");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // init world
    private static void init()
    {
        nPeople = sc.nextInt();
        queries = sc.nextInt();
        world = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= nPeople ; i++)  world.add(i);
    }

    // get the community of specified person 
    // return size
    private static int query(Integer person)
    {
        return getCommunity(person).size();
    }

    // check that the two specified persons do not belong to same community 
    // get the two communities of specified persons 
    // iterate over list of persons of comunity2, 
    // set them to community (value) of person1 
    private static void merge(Integer person1, Integer person2)
    {
        if (world.get(person1).equals(world.get(person2))) return;

        List<Integer> community1 = getCommunity(person1);
        List<Integer> community2 = getCommunity(person2);
        if (community1.isEmpty() || community2.isEmpty()) return;

        Integer community1Id = world.get(community1.get(0)); 
        for (Integer person : community2) {
            world.set(person, community1Id);
        }
    }

    // returns list of persons (indexes in world) 
    // that belong to community (value) of specified person
    private static List<Integer> getCommunity(Integer person)
    {
        List<Integer> community = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < world.size() ; i++) {
            if (world.get(i).equals(world.get(person))) {
                community.add(i);
            }
        }
        return community;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete code of a solution that passes all the test cases.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
static int parent[],rank[],m[];
static int find(int i)
{
    if(i==parent[i])
    return i;
   int res=find(parent[i]);
   parent[i]=res;
        return res;

}

static void union(int i,int j)
{
    int irep=find(i),jrep=find(j);
    if(irep==jrep)
    return;
    if(rank[irep]>rank[jrep])
    {
        parent[jrep]=irep;
        m[irep]+=m[jrep];
    }
    else if(rank[irep]<rank[jrep])
    {
        parent[irep]=jrep;
        m[jrep]+=m[irep];
    }
    else
    {
        parent[jrep]=irep;
        rank[irep]++;
        m[irep]+=m[jrep];
    }



}
public static void main(String []args)throws IOException
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt(),q=sc.nextInt();
parent=new int[n+1];
rank=new int[n+1];
m=new int[n+1];
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
    parent[i]=i;
    rank[i]=1;
    m[i]=1;

}
for(int i=0;i<q;i++)
    {

    switch(sc.next().charAt(0))
        {
        case 'Q':
        int c=0;

        System.out.println(m[find(sc.nextInt())]);
        break;
        case 'M':
        union(sc.nextInt(),sc.nextInt());
        break;

    }

}

}



}
```